# How do I make a loop of the string "For hes a jolly good fellow" loop 3x / Rubric attached on specific requirments

Tags: visual-studio, loops, assembly

How do I add a loop to print out For hes a jolly good fellow 3x? Heres the rubric requirement: You must only have one call to the printf()function to output the “For he's a jolly good fellow!” string and must use a loop with a jump instruction to output the string three time

````
    global  _main
    extern  _printf
    extern  _ExitProcess@4

section .bss
name:      resb 100
position1: resz 1
position2: resz 1
position3: resz 1


section .data
jolly:  db "For he's is a jolly good fellow!", 0ah, 0
deny:   db 'Which nobody can deny!', 0ah, 0

section .text
        
_main:
       
        push   jolly         ;  push the jolly string and call printf
        call   _printf
        add    esp, 4        ;  restore the stack pointer


        push   deny          ;  push the deny string and call printf
        call   _printf
        add    esp, 4        ;  restore the stack pointer

        xor     ecx,ecx      ;  set the exit code to 0

        call    _ExitProcess@4
    ```
````

Comment: Use the [edit] link and the code formatting button to fix your question. Anyway, you don't seem to have the printing in the loop body so of course that won't work. Also, `printf` will destroy `ecx` so you will need to save that yourself.

Comment: Ok I fixed the format i believe and would should i do to fix the loop body

Comment: That looks like NASM syntax; make sure you're building with NASM, not the MASM assembler that comes with Visual Studio.  Anyway, pick any call-preserved register to use as a loop counter.

Answer (score 0):

Find a working *Hello,world* example and learn how to make an executable program from it.
Then feel free to modify it to print other greetings.
Instead of NASM or MASM you might also like [€ASM](https://euroassembler.eu/download/) which makes creating Windows programs easy:
`euroasm Jolly.asm` will produce the final executable file `Jolly.exe`.
The EuroAssembler source `Jolly.asm` would look like this:

```
Jolly PROGRAM Format=PE,Width=32,Entry=_main
        INCLUDE winapi.htm   ; Fetch macros StdOutput and TerminateProgram.
[.data]
jolly:  db "For he's is a jolly good fellow!", 0ah, 0
deny:   db 'Which nobody can deny!', 0ah, 0
[.text]
_main:  MOV EBX,3            ; How many times the loop repeats.
print:  StdOutput jolly      ; Write ASCIIZ string using a macro 'StdOutput'.
        DEC EBX              ; Consult the loop counter.
        JNZ print            ; Loop to print again while EBX>0.
        StdOutput deny       ; Write the other ASCIIZ string.
        TerminateProgram     ; Invoke ExitProcess using a macro.
       ENDPROGRAM
```

You have asked the same question [How do you make a loop in x86 assembly language to repeat a line of text 3 times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68512747/how-do-you-make-a-loop-in-x86-assembly-language-to-repeat-a-line-of-text-3-times) four days ago, please don't repeat the same questions.